# Parse second regex match only (webserver logs)?

Tags: python, regex, logfile

I have the following (AWS load balancer format) log file example line that I would like to parse.

```
http 2017-08-01T00:25:06.644602Z app/webservices/2f179337c6c8adb5
46.229.168.65:7336 172.31.26.99:82 0.000 0.574 0.000 200 200 257 192227 "GET http://trac.navit-project.org:80/timeline?from=2011-04-16T07%3A23%3A03Z&precision=second HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/1.2~bl;
+http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)" - - arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:712275310776:targetgroup/trac/34e2ac9af93f42de "Root=1-597fca61-4dfde4b02cd92cf61ace9825"
```

I have a regex that is at least partially working that looks like the following:

```
match = re.search(r'\"(?P<agent>.*?)\"', line)
print(match)
```

The problem is that the regex is only matching the first set of quotes in the above log line.

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(138, 241), match='"GET http://trac.navit-project.org:80/timeline?fr>
```

Is there a way to modify it to look for the second match so I can parse the user agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the regex to

```
"[^"]+"[^"]+"(?P<agent>[^"]*)"
```

explanation:

```
"                     # opening first "-set
[^"]+                 # followed by anything not equal to "
"                     # closing first "
[^"]+                 # followed by anything not equal to "
"                     # opening second "-set
(?P<agent>[^"]*)      # named group agent
"                     # closing "
```